# Laravel, get all orders of the stores in one group if the stores have the same group id

Tags: php, laravel

I'm stuck in a very complex problem, I have stores, groups, and orders table
I want to show all orders of all stores that have the same group id
I tried but what I get is group of stores individually 
please check the screenshot you will understand my issue

For grouped stores I think should show both the group and the store

thank you in advance

```
// show the last 7 days report
public function getSalesStores()
{
    $weekStart = Carbon::parse('last Sunday')->subdays(7);
    $weekEnd = $weekStart->copy()->adddays(7);

    $allusers = User::getAllUsers();
    $allgroups = storeGroup::getAllGroups();

    $allstores = Storeinfo::select('id', 'store_name', 'site_percent', 'fee_type', 'store_group_id')
        ->whereHas('userorders', function ($query) use ($weekStart, $weekEnd) {
            $query->whereBetween('order_date', [$weekStart, $weekEnd]);
        })
        ->with(['userorders' => function ($query) use ($weekStart, $weekEnd) {
            $query
                ->whereBetween('order_date', [$weekStart, $weekEnd])
                ->whereNotIn('confirmed', ['c', 'a', 'r'])
                ->groupBy('userorders.order_number');
        }])
        ->orderBy('storeinfos.store_name')
        ->get();

        $groupedStores = $allstores->where('store_group_id', '!=', null);


return view('managedashboard.cservicedashboard.sales_orders_bystore.archive', compact('allusers', 'allstores','allgroups','groupedStores'));
}
```

**Blade:**

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="postTable">
    <p class="tabletitle">Sales Report</p>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="textcenter">Store</th>
        <th class="textcenter">Total</th>
        <th class="textcenter">our fee</th>
        <th class="textcenter">Pay to store</th>
        <th class="textcenter">Order number</th>
        <th class="textcenter">Date</th>
        <th class="textcenter">Store Name</th>
        <th class="textcenter">Customer Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>   
    @foreach($groupedStores as $key => $store) 

        @php 
            $class = $key % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'; 
            $fee=0; 
        @endphp
    <tr class="{{$class}}">
        <td class="storename" rowspan="{{ $store->userorders->count() + 1 }}">               
                  @foreach($allgroups as $allgroup) 
                        @if(($store->store_group_id)==$allgroup->id) 
                            {{$allgroup->name}}
                          @endif   
                   @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
     @foreach($store->userorders as $userorder)

            <tr>
                <td class="textcenter">
                    {{number_format($userorder->totalpayment, 2, '.', ',')}}
                </td>

                <td class="textcenter">

                    @if($store->fee_type=='total') 
                        {{number_format(($userorder->totalpayment * ($store->site_percent / 100)), 2, '.', ',')}} 
                        @else 
                        {{number_format(($userorder->order_subtotal * ($store->site_percent / 100)), 2, '.', ',')}}

                    @endif 

                    @php 
                            if($store->fee_type=='total') { 
                            $fee = $fee + number_format(($userorder->totalpayment * ($store->site_percent/100)), 2, '.', ','); 
                                                 } 
                        else { 
                               $fee = $fee + number_format(($userorder->order_subtotal *
                               ($store->site_percent/100)), 2, '.', ','); 
                              } 
                    @endphp
                </td>

                <td class="textcenter">
                    <!-- Pay to Store -->
                    @if($store->fee_type=='total') 
                        {{number_format(($userorder->totalpayment - ($userorder->totalpayment * ($store->site_percent/100))), 2, '.', ',')}} 

                        @else 
                            {{number_format(($userorder->totalpayment -
                            ($userorder->order_subtotal * ($store->site_percent/100))), 2, '.', ',')}} 
                    @endif
                </td>

                <td class="textcenter">
                    {{$userorder->order_number}}
                </td>

                <td class="textcenter">
                    {{date('D d M, Y', strtotime($userorder->order_date))}}
                </td>

                <!--  Store Name  -->
                <td class="textcenter">
                    @foreach($allusers as $alluser) 
                        @if(($userorder->user_id)==$alluser->id) 
                            {{$alluser->fname}} 
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </td>

                <!--  Customer Name  -->
                <td class="textcenter">
                    @foreach($allusers as $alluser) 
                        @if(($userorder->user_id)==$alluser->id) 
                            {{$alluser->fname}} 
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            </tr>


            @endforeach <!-- end orders loop -->

    <tr>
        <td class="totalstyle">TOTAL</td>
        <td class="totalstyle">
            {{number_format($store->userorders->sum('totalpayment'), 2, '.', ',')}}
        </td>

        <td class="totalstyle">
            {{$fee}}
        </td>

        <td class="totalstyle">
            {{number_format($store->userorders->sum('totalpayment')-($fee), 2, '.', ',')}}
        </td>
    </tr>

    @endforeach <!-- end main store loop -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to grab the query the data and reformat it accordingly. Then you can simply display the data in view using foreach loop. For the models StoreGroup, Store and Order, you can do something like given below. That would give u data in the format specified in "result" section of the attachment.

```
$storeGroupNames = StoreGroup::query()
    ->pluck('name', 'id');
$data = Order::query()
    ->with('store')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function (Order $order) {
        return $order->store->store_group_id;
    })
    ->mapWithKeys(function (Collection $orders, $storeGroupId) use ($storeGroupNames) {
        $storeGroupName = $storeGroupNames->get($storeGroupId);

        return [$storeGroupName => $orders];
    });
dd($data);
```

Comment: Thats just pseudo code. You can update the query with conditions as you are doing in original query